# Get off private-net back to main Mist

Tags: mist, akasha

I installed and used Akasha but then when I opened Mist next it said it was on Private-net. I tried "geth --networkid 1" but that didn't do anything.

What are some things I could try to fix this?

Comment: Try launching mist with `--networkid 1`

Comment: Thanks, I tried that but it didn't work. The only way I can get it to work is by renaming chaindata to chaindataBACKUP, essentially deleting it. I would really rather not download that again.

I did also try removing the MANIFEST-xxxxxx file but that caused geth to not run completely.